# How to reduce Volume Group size in LVM on Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, partition, lvm

I'm having problems resizing an LVM using a Fedora24 Live CD.

This is the output for **vgdisplay**:

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               349.95 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              89588
  Alloc PE / Size       27585 / 107.75 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       62003 / 242.20 GiB
  VG UUID               db5n4Z-1C2C-KC2e-Xuek-uHGu-js9M-0gV3IY
```

And this is the output for **pvdidplay**:

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               349.96 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              89588
  Free PE               62003
  Allocated PE          27585
  PV UUID               eWJSCP-hMmO-JdNg-YNZl-L00h-N3Q8-aLmVpz
```

I want to reduce linux disk to give free space to Windows partition (/dev/sda1). But when i try this command:

```
lvm pvresize -v --setphysicalvolumesize 209897472K /dev/sda5
```

...I get this output:

```
Wiping internal VG cache
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
    Archiving volume group "fedora" metadata (seqno 5).
    /dev/sda5: Pretending size is 419794944 not 733908992 sectors.
    Resizing volume "/dev/sda5" to 419794944 sectors.
    Resizing physical volume /dev/sda5 from 0 to 51244 extents.
  /dev/sda5: cannot resize to 51244 extents as later ones are allocated.
  0 physical volume(s) resized / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
```

**How can I shrink my linux disk?**

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the answer is hidden in the message:

> cannot resize to 51244 extents as later ones are allocated

What LVM is trying to say is that even though you're using 107.75 GiB, and you want to shrink the PV to 209.9 GiB  --which is enough room for the data-- the *filesystem* itself has allocated disk space beyond the 209.9 GiB boundary.

It may be easier to understand this with an illustration. Imagine your PV looks like this, where *x* represents used up space:

```
|------------------------------|
|  x x x x x  x         x x    | 349.96 GiB
|------------------------------|
```

When you try to resize the PV to 209.0 GiB, you're asking for this:

```
|------------\            \------------------|
|  x x x x x / 209.0 GiB  /x         x x     | 
|------------\            \------------------|
```

It's like cutting a stick of butter with a knife. As you can see, some of the used space is on that second portion. If LVM were to allow you to *cut* your PV like this, you'd end up with a corrupted filesystem; so be thankful it said *no!*

So what you have to do first is resize the partition. That's going to depend on the filesystem type, but ext4, btrfs, and the like have resizing tools. Resizing the filesystem will pack the extends so that you can get a clean *cut* when you resize the LVM.

```
 .............| 209.9 Gib
|------------------------------|
|xxxxxxxx                      | 349.96 GiB
|------------------------------|
```